# Trying to add styling to Wordpress site logo

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to add some CSS to a Wordpress site logo and it's driving me nuts. Here is the html:

```
<div id="main-container">
    <header id="top-header" >
        <div id="logo">
            <a href="http://somesite.com/"><img src="http://somesite.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/cropped-cropped-logo2251.jpg" width="175" height="194" alt="somesite Wood logo"/></a>
        </div><!-- end of #logo -->
        <div id="main-navigation">
            <div class="social-icons">
                <ul>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

And here are the CSS variations I have tried but do not work:

```
#logo a img { 
    opacity: 0.85;
}
#logo a { 
        opacity: 0.85;
}
#top-header #logo a img { 
        opacity: 0.85;
}
#logo img { 
        opacity: 0.85;
}
```

Link to the site is here: [www.patchwood.ca](http://www.patchwood.ca)

Comment: why do you open a ul and close it right after?

Comment: Send the link where this website is hosted. As the HTML/CSS you are providing is without the wordpress CSS that is overriding it.

Comment: @ErikMes it's a Wordpress template so not sure why it's like that there could be some PHP code at play

Comment: @NathanLee I've added the link

Comment: Working for me http://jsfiddle.net/fYt25/

Comment: Works in Firefox 21, Chrome, Safari, as for IE - you might need to use the filter property: [Cross Browser Opacity](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/cross-browser-opacity/)

Comment: Appears to be a browser cache issue, I noticed the CSS working in a fresh browser

Comment: Actually, i have just noticed that your opacity:0.85; is working fine, try and set it to .5 to see the difference

Answer (score 0):

Appears to be a browser cache issue, I noticed the CSS working in a fresh browser